# Drop Down Value Not Returning To Default ng-if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the below angular form, using ng-if the drop downs appear when a radio button is clicked. When a different radio button is clicked again the drop downs go to a blank value, I would like them to go back to the "Choose" option. How do I do that?

```
<form name="addToolForm" ng-submit="vm.addStuff()">
    <div layout="row" style="padding-left:30px">
        <md-radio-group name="firstCategory" ng-model="vm.firstCategory" layout="row" ng-required="true">
            <md-radio-button value="item1">item1</md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button value="item2">item2</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="secondCategory" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.firstCategory == 'item1'">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select name="secondCategory" ng-model="vm.secondCategory" ng-dropdown required="true">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
                <option ng-option value="option1">option1</option>
                <option ng-option value="option2">option2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="secondCategory" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.firstCategory == 'item2'">
        <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <select name="secondCategory" ng-model="vm.secondCategory" ng-dropdown required="true">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
                <option ng-option value="option1">option3</option>
                <option ng-option value="option2">option4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is going to be to use [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) on the `vm.firstCategory` to set `vm.secondCatefory` to an empty string, like so

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
  <div layout="row" style="padding-left:30px">
    <md-radio-group name="firstCategory" ng-model="vm.firstCategory" layout="row" ng-required="true" ng-change="vm.secondCategory = ''">
      <md-radio-button value="item1">item1</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="item2">item2</md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="secondCategory" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.firstCategory == 'item1'">
    <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <select name="secondCategory" ng-model="vm.secondCategory" ng-dropdown required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
        <option ng-option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option ng-option value="option2">option2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="secondCategory" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.firstCategory == 'item2'">
    <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <select name="secondCategory" ng-model="vm.secondCategory" ng-dropdown required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
        <option ng-option value="option1">option3</option>
        <option ng-option value="option2">option4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

But because you're using [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) the dom elements will get removed, in this case it's not such a bad thing as it means you can use [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) which allows you to set a value any time the element it's on is rendered so changing your code to below should get it to work.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller("MyCtrl", MyCtrl);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var vm = this;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">


  <div layout="row" style="padding-left:30px">
    <md-radio-group name="firstCategory" ng-model="vm.firstCategory" layout="row" ng-required="true">
      <md-radio-button value="item1">item1</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="item2">item2</md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="secondCategory" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.firstCategory == 'item1'">
    <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <select name="secondCategory" ng-model="vm.secondCategory" ng-init="vm.secondCategory = ''" ng-dropdown required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
        <option ng-option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option ng-option value="option2">option2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12" id="secondCategory" style="padding-left:30px" ng-if="vm.firstCategory == 'item2'">
    <label class="col-xs-6 control-label">Sub Type:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <select name="secondCategory" ng-model="vm.secondCategory" ng-init="vm.secondCategory = ''" ng-dropdown required="true">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
        <option ng-option value="option1">option3</option>
        <option ng-option value="option2">option4</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---